# Toolset change to Win XP friendly rises _CLSID_WICImagingFactory1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

After setting Platform Toolset to `Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp)` I got linking error `unresolved external symbol _CLSID_WICImagingFactory1`. With `Visual Studio 2012 (v110)` toolset everything goes fine. How to solve this problem?

Comment: At least one of your .lib or .obj files is being compiled with the wrong SDK version.  You must make sure that **all** of your libraries are compiled with the v110_xp toolset in effect.  The linker error should tell you which .obj is the trouble-maker.

Answer (score 0):

This is because somewhere you have a library built with the Windows 8.0 SDK version of the wincodec.h header:

```
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_WICImagingFactory1, 0xcacaf262, ...
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_WICImagingFactory2, 0x317d06e8, ...
#if(_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8) || defined(_WIN7_PLATFORM_UPDATE)
#define WINCODEC_SDK_VERSION WINCODEC_SDK_VERSION2
#define CLSID_WICImagingFactory CLSID_WICImagingFactory2
#else
#define WINCODEC_SDK_VERSION WINCODEC_SDK_VERSION1
#endif
```

For Windows XP, you must be using the Windows 7.1A SDK which is what the "v110_xp" Platform Toolset does. which only has:

```
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_WICImagingFactory,  0xcacaf262, ...
```

Then when you link your app, you are linking against the Windows 7.1A SDK version of the uuid.lib which does not have CLSID_WICImagingFactory1 or CLSID_WICImagingFactory2 defined.

The reason that the Windows 8.x SDK has two versions of the factory is to let you use the WIC2 version on Windows 8.x or Windows 7 SP1 with KB [2670838](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838/), but if building for Windows Vista or Windows 7 RTM you have to use WIC1.

See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/19/windows-imaging-component-and-windows-8.aspx) for more detail on WIC2. Be sure to read this [Visual C++ team blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx) and this [DirectX SDK blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/26/visual-studio-2012-update-1.aspx) for important details about using the Windows XP Platform Toolset.